# Codeigniter Routing?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, admin

I am having a problem with my routing in Codeigniter Project. Actually I have created the admin folder under the controller,view and model to access the admin section.And my routes.php file is as below:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "admin/login";
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/admin/$1";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

When I click on the submit button of the login page it redirects to the same page of login. 
The action where it should actually go its not redirecting there.

Comment: You should really not be using [code igniter](http://www.scribd.com/doc/148943699/CodeIgniter-Sucks)

Comment: What is Code Ignitor?

Comment: What is the action of the form that you have generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In routes.php file :

```
$route['default_controller'] = "your default controller";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

In htaccess

```
#Options +FollowSymlinks
#RewriteEngine on
#
#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|uploads|tt|resources|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|cronDailyProof\.php|cronWeeklyProof\.php|cronMonthlyProof\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

The above two changes solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

check the form tag. may be it have an **action** in it. and your button type maybe **submit**
please remove and check again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use another CI instance in your project then keep it in your project folder as given below :

```
 /project
    /application
    /admin
    /system
```

In your admin folder you should have another CI project from where you'll create your admin panel.

```
 /project/admin
       /application
       /system
```

You can set your configuration and routing and whatever you want from any of your project as you desire.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It is the right solution ...but I when i have changed my route.php file and htaccess file ..then my project was running perfectly fine without following above folder structure.

Comment: that may work fine...but that's not the standrd, as when you'll make a bigger project with lots of files, then it's quite possible that you'll lose track. So it's better that you organize your files properly. There is another solution, which is following hmvc....where in a single CI instance you can have multiple modules. Under each module you can create your desired functionality. For example you can have a module named 'frontend' and another named 'admin'

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc and http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/hmvc-an-introduction-and-application--net-11850 ...read these ...u'll find hmvc very fascinating ....:D

Comment: Yes exactly nizu...you are absolutely right...that's why i have not followed above solution...

Answer (score 0):

in route.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = 'errors';
$route['admin'] = 'admin/login';
```

and in htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
rewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

these changes solved this problem for me

Answer (score 0):

If u have to follow for default_controller home controller working then home controller working and not page available then pagenotfound controller work.
on my default page to move on login page onclicking login button.
then follw like this

```
<?php
                    $attributes = array("class" => "form-horizontal", "id" => "loginform", "name" => "loginform");
                    echo form_open("login/index", $attributes);
                ?>
//login button like this and its working
<button type="submit" name="btn_login" id="btn_login" class="btn btn-default" value="Login"><?php echo lang('Login'); ?></button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>

My Route.php file

$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = 'pagenotfound';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

My .htaccess file

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|admin|js|css|images|assets|uploads|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```